# Removable singularities of harmonic functions question

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

There seems to be a removable singularity theorem for harmonic functions that somewhat goes like:

> Let $\Omega\subset \Bbb R^n$ be an open region and $x_0\in\Omega$, $u$ is harmonic in $\Omega-\{x_0\}$. Now if we have $u(x)=o(\Phi(x-x_0))$ around $x_0$ then there exists $\tilde u$ harmonic in all of $\Omega$ and $u=\tilde u$ in $\Omega-\{x_0\}$.

Here $\Phi$ is the fundamental solution to $\Delta u=0$ in $\Bbb R^n$, and, since dropping the normalising constant doesn't affect our statement above, you may just take $\Phi=-\log|x-x_0|$ in 2D and $=1/|x-x_0|^{n-2}$ in 3D or higher.

I have a question concerning this theorem:
I found [this one](http://www.math.unipd.it/%7Eacesar/docs/didattica/removable.pdf), which I am not sure about :

Let $w=u-\tilde{u} .$ Then $w$ is harmonic in $B\left(x_{0}, r\right) \backslash\left\{x_{0}\right\}$ and moreover (check it!)
$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow x_{0}} \frac{w(x)}{r^{2-n}-\left|x-x_{0}\right|^{2-n}}=0 \quad \text { if } n \geq 3 \quad \lim _{x \rightarrow x_{0}} \frac{w(x)}{\log r-\log \left|x-x_{0}\right|}=0 \text { if } n=2
$$
So for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for all $x$ such that $\left|x-x_{0}\right| \leq \delta$,
$$
|w(x)| \leq \varepsilon\left(r^{2-n}-\left|x-x_{0}\right|^{2-n}\right) \text { if } n \geq 3 \quad|w(x)| \leq \varepsilon\left(\log r-\log \left|x-x_{0}\right|\right) \quad \text { if } n=2
$$

Because I know $u(x)=o(\Phi(x-x_0))$ but I cannot see too easy that $w(x)=o(\Phi(x-x_0)).$ Is that correct or there is a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\tilde u$ is bounded in $B(x_0,r)$, $w=u-\tilde u=o(\Phi(x-x_0))$ as $x\to x_0$:
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\frac{w(x)}{\Phi(x-x_0)}=\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\frac{u(x)-\tilde u(x)}{\Phi(x-x_0)}=0
$$
since $\Phi(x-x_0)\to\infty$ as $x\to x_0$ and $\tilde u(x)$ is bounded.

Comment: And what is the reason to say in the proof that $w(x)=0$ with $x \neq x_0$?

Comment: You have $w=0$ on the boundary of your ball with radius $r$, and $|w|$ is dominated by harmonic functions which are zero on the boundary of the same ball and hence are zero everywhere (by the maximum principle, or if you want by uniqueness of the solution of the Dirichlet problem on the ball). Therefore $|w|=0$ and $u$ actually coincides with the nice function $\tilde u$. That is, singularities less severe than the singularity of $\Phi(\cdot-x_0)$ are not possible.